# Embedded twitch link, AWS Cognito error 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitch

I'm embedding twitch player in an iframe on my site and I'm getting a javascript error saying error 400 posting to "https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/". It's the actual twitch player that is trying to post to the AWS site (example embedded url below). So I'm wondering how do I make this error go away.

Example embedded URL (check dev-tools should see error 400 connecting to aws cognito server):

https://player.twitch.tv/?video=783306182&parent=localhost&autoplay=false&muted=true

Answer (score 0):

I asked this on the twitch developer forums and they said this error was in their side, likely due to outages. So not something I can make go away when embedding their videos in iframe.

https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/embedded-twitch-player-link-aws-cognito-error-400/29714